# Unit testing of control drawing in GDI

Tags: unit-testing, winapi, drawing, gdi

I have a control written in C++ using WinAPI and I would like to automatically test that it is being drawn properly. I can either compare the drawn image with saved reference images or simply test that specific pixels have specific color. I have both types implemented.

The problem is that the tests now also run every night on a virtual machine which for some reason has only 16bit color depth. This causes the colors to be slightly off. I have tried to come up with colors that wouldn't be changed when drawn in 16bit color depth, but the rounding scheme seems to be rather complicated and I need the tests to be functional in both 32b an 16b color depths.

Another idea was to create an offscreen bitmap that would always have 32b color depth. It would have the benefit that the tests would use the same environment every time,but I couldn't get that to work. How can I create a 32b HBITMAP and HDC regardless of the screen color depth? Or do you have any other tips how to solve the general problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I create a 32b HBITMAP and HDC
>   regardless of the screen color depth?

it's simple:

```
BITMAPINFO bmp_info = {};
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biHeight = height;
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
bmp_info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

HDC mem_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(0);
void *dummy;
HBITMAP bitmap_handle = CreateDIBSection(mem_dc, &bmp_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, &dummy, NULL, 0);
SelectObject(mem_dc, bitmap_handle));
```

now draw your button over this DC. Remember to check for errors and to release resources.

Or alternatively, automatically convert your button reference view to actual desktop mode:

```
HWND desktop = GetDesktopWindow();
HDC desktop_dc = GetDC(desktop);
HDC mem_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(desktop_dc); 
RECT rect;
GetClientRect(desktop, &rect);
HBITMAP bitmap_handle = CreateCompatibleBitmap(desktop_dc, rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top);
SelectObject(mem_dc, bitmap_handle);
```

and now BitBlt your preloaded image over `mem_dc`. It will be automatically converted to current desktop color mode

Comment: I tried exactly this code, but it seems that creating the mem_dc from 0 (the screen) makes it 16b again, so it doesn't work.

Comment: @Roman: I created mem_dc to be 4bpp, 8bpp and 16bpp successfully on my 32bpp color windows. do you mean that upscaling doesn't work? pls recheck. also the problem can be related with code that compares your result with reference image

Comment: This code actually works, I found a bug in mine thanks to your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've done GDI unit testing by drawing into a WMF (now EMF) file.  It did replicate the resolution and DPI of a source (and the later destination) device, but I don't recall if color depth was a "sticky" attribute.   Even if it was, since the fileformat allows you to capture/replay the GDI sequence, you might have a more accurate unit test in the end anyways.   We'd interpret the WMF file to make sure we generated what we thought we should.

[CreateEnhMetaFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183498%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

What about using GDI+ to create the offscreen bitmap, and then drawing to it with GDI - something like this:

```
int width=64; // or whatever you need
int height=100;
int stride = width*4;
BYTE buffer[stride*height];
Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat32bppARGB, buffer);
Gdiplus::Graphics g (&bitmap);
HDC dc = g.GetHDC();

// drawing code, using WinAPI, to draw to dc

g.ReleaseHDC();

// Now compare the contents of your buffer
```

More about gdi / gdi+ interop here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311221

Comment: I ended up loading images using GDI+, because OleLoadPicture doesn't work in different color depths than the desktop, so thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Change your test to pass if comparison against the 32 bit image or against the 16 bit image is OK.  Capture both 32 bit versions and 16 bit versions (running virtual).  This is really quick and easy to implement.

You should already have an automatic way to capture the reference images for a known good version of the code.  If you don't, do that now, as it will save you time later when you make small changes to the appearance of the control.  You now have the reference for regression testing.

Answer (score 0):

Either create a 32bpp offscreen surface like you said, or perform the exact same operation with your comparison reference image so you are testing both at the same bpp. In other words don't do your own rounding; let the GDI system do the same rounding to both surfaces.